# How to setup e-mail settings to maintain conversations?

Tags: settings, email, gmail

My brother has a WP7 phone, and when he answers to my e-mails, it becomes a new conversation in Gmail. If we write to each other in the same subject e.g. 8 times, I will have at least four conversations in Gmail, each with 2 letters in it. How can he turn off the insertion of the "RE:" word into his e-mail subjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to remove the Re: from the reply email subject unless he does it manually every time. The Re: is inserted in a lot of mail programs so this is not specific to windows phone.

It sounds to me like this is a problem with Gmail not grouping the emails correctly rather than windows phone doing something wrong.